# Fixed serial number to same name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to have an Arrayformula at A1 to produce this output:
[image]
I want to have a same serial number for same names, names would not be sorted & could repeat any number of time.

[Google Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vkdQa734PeUTn5i8xVV-raQmg_tXe86mM29L5_Pk5aY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plz try:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(match(B2:B,unique(B2:B),0)))
```